# How to get Nuxt-img to work on nuxt3 generate?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3, static-site-generation

i am trying to use nuxt-image on NUXT3,  but it seems it doesn't work with the generate command.  Images work during dev,  but get a 404 when using nuxt generate.

in my nuxt config i have

```
modules: ["@nuxt/image-edge"],  
image: {
    dir: "assets/images",
  },
```

then in my files i have

```
<NuxtImg
      format="webp"
      class="mobile"
      src="/website/home/above-fold-illustration-mobile.png"
      alt="illustration"
      aria-hidden="true"
    />
```

So i am wondering if anyone else had a problem or if this is just a compatibility issue with nuxt-image and nuxt3 generate

Comment: Where do you host it? How do you try to preview the generate website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is not yet supported, waiting on https://github.com/nuxt/image/pull/614

Answer (score 0):

Reading this [part of the documentation](https://image.nuxtjs.org/api/options#dir)

> For static provider, if images weren't crawled during generation (unreachable modals, pages or dynamic runtime size), changing dir from static causes 404 errors.

There are other few bugs if you change `dir` to something else than `static` apparently.
Can't you stick to `static`? Will probably avoid you quite some issues IMO.

Comment: so `static` is the default option.   and even if i dont use dir and move my images to public this component still breaks on generate

Comment: Hm, right it's `public` in Nuxt3 now and not `static` anymore. Maybe update the dir to be `public` so. @Jean-PierreEngelbrecht

Comment: just tested it,  even when setting dir to public it still doesnt work.    what is odd for me is that it works in dev mode but not on static generation,  so i am wondering if this is just some compatibility issue

Comment: The fact that it works in dev is not surprising at all since it's far easier to setup when you have an actively running dev server. Totally legit. I'm not sure if there are not some things that may be related to your issues: https://github.com/nuxt/image/issues?q=is%3Aissue+static+ I'm not sure that `@nuxt/image-edge` is still the way to go tho, since I saw some people successfully running their thing without the latest version.

Comment: so i think only image-edge supports nuxt3 at this point. https://v1.image.nuxtjs.org/get-started/

Comment: Nvm, you're damn right haha.

Comment: Not working for me either with Nuxt3, posted a comment here https://github.com/nuxt/image/issues/215#issuecomment-1692573101. Will look into nuxt/image-edge.

Answer (score 0):

In my case for nuxt3 in nuxt.config.ts:

```
modules: ['@nuxt/image-edge'],
image: { dir: 'assets/img' }
```

Inside assets/img there is a file 'logo.png'

if I write src like
`<NuxtImg src="logo.png" format="wepb"/>` - it works in dev and error to get file after build and start

But if src starts with '/' like `<NuxtImg src="/logo.png" format="wepb"/>` - it perfectly works in dev and after build